# Unit testing a kafka topology that's using kstream joins

Tags: java, unit-testing, join, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a topology that does two kstream joins, the problem im facing is when trying to unit test with the TopologyTestDriver sending a couple of ConsumerRecords with pipeInput and then readOutput. It seems not to be working.

Im thinking this might be because the joins is using the internal rocksdb in the actual kafka which we dont use in the tests.

So i've been looking around for a solution for this but cant find any.

Note: This method of testing works perfectly fine when removing the kstream-kstream joins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have a topology that does two kstream joins, the problem im facing is when trying to unit test with the TopologyTestDriver sending a couple of ConsumerRecords with pipeInput and then readOutput. It seems not to be working.

By design, but unfortunately in your case, the `TopologyTestDriver` isn't a 100% accurate model of how the Kafka Streams engine works at runtime.  Notably, there are some differences in the processing order of new, incoming events.

This can indeed cause problems when trying to test, for example, certain joins because these operations depend on a certain processing order (e.g., in a stream-table join, the table should already have an entry for key 'alice' before a stream-side event for 'alice' arrives, otherwise the join output for the stream-side 'alice' will not include any table-side data).

> So i've been looking around for a solution for this but cant find any.

What I suggest is to use tests that spin up an embedded Kafka cluster, and then run your tests against that cluster using the "real" Kafka Streams engine (i.e., not the `TopologyTestDriver`). Effectively, this means you are changing your tests from unit tests to integration/system tests: your test will launch a full-fledged Kafka Streams topology that talks to the embedded Kafka cluster that runs on the same machine as your test.

See the integration tests for Kafka Streams in the Apache Kafka project, where [`EmbeddedKafkaCluster`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/test/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/integration/utils/EmbeddedKafkaCluster.java) and [`IntegrationTestUtils`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/test/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/integration/utils/IntegrationTestUtils.java) are the center pieces for the tooling. A concrete test example for joins is [`StreamTableJoinIntegrationTest`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/test/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/integration/StreamTableJoinIntegrationTest.java) (there are a few join related integration tests) with its parent [`AbstractJoinIntegrationTest`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/test/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/integration/AbstractJoinIntegrationTest.java). (For what it's worth, there are further integration tests examples at https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples#examples-integration-tests, which includes tests that also cover Confluent Schema Registry when using Apache Avro as your data format, etc.)

However, unless I am mistaken, the integration tests and their tooling *are not* included in the [test utilities](https://kafka.apache.org/24/documentation/streams/developer-guide/testing.html) artifact of Kafka Streams (i.e., `org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams-test-utils`). So you'd have to do some copy-pasting into your own code base.

Answer (score 2):

Have you had a look at the Kafka Streams unit tests [1]? It's about piping in the data and checking the end result with a mock processor.

For example for the following stream join:

```
        stream1 = builder.stream(topic1, consumed);
        stream2 = builder.stream(topic2, consumed);
        joined = stream1.outerJoin(
            stream2,
            MockValueJoiner.TOSTRING_JOINER,
            JoinWindows.of(ofMillis(100)),
            StreamJoined.with(Serdes.Integer(), Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));
        joined.process(supplier);
```

You can then start piping input items into the first or second topic and check with each successive piping of input, what the processor can check:

```
// push two items to the primary stream; the other window is empty
            // w1 = {}
            // w2 = {}
            // --> w1 = { 0:A0, 1:A1 }
            //     w2 = {}
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                inputTopic1.pipeInput(expectedKeys[i], "A" + expectedKeys[i]);
            }
            processor.checkAndClearProcessResult(EMPTY);

            // push two items to the other stream; this should produce two items
            // w1 = { 0:A0, 1:A1 }
            // w2 = {}
            // --> w1 = { 0:A0, 1:A1 }
            //     w2 = { 0:a0, 1:a1 }
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                inputTopic2.pipeInput(expectedKeys[i], "a" + expectedKeys[i]);
            }
            processor.checkAndClearProcessResult(new KeyValueTimestamp<>(0, "A0+a0", 0),
                new KeyValueTimestamp<>(1, "A1+a1", 0));
```

I hope this helps.

References:
[1] https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/test/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/internals/KStreamKStreamJoinTest.java#L279